# What is proper design for system with external database and RESTful web gui and service?

Tags: scala, database-design, rest, architecture, playframework

Basically I started to design my project to be like that:

1. Play! Framework for web gui (consuming RESTful service)
2. Spray Framework for RESTful service, connects to database, process incoming data, serves data for web gui
3. Database. Only service have rights to access it

Now I'm wondering, if it's really best possible design.
In fact with Play! I could easily have both web gui and service hosted at once.
That would be much easier to test and deploy in simple cases probably.
In complicated cases when high performance is needed I still can run one instance purely for gui and few next just to work as services (even if each of them could still serve full functionality).
On the other side I'm not sure if it won't hit performance too hard (services will be processing a lot of data, not only from the web gui). Also, isn't it mixing things which I should keep separated?

If I'll decide to keep them separated, should I allow to connect to database only through RESTful service? How to resolve problem with service and web gui trying to use different version of database? Should I use versioned REST protocol in that case?

----------------- EDIT------------------
My current system structure looks like that:
[image]

But I'm wondering if it wouldn't make sense to simplify it by putting RESTful service inside Play! gui web server directly.

----------------- EDIT 2------------------
Here is the diagram which illustrates my main question.
To say it clearly in other words: would it be bad to connect my service and web gui and share the model? And why? 
Because there is also few advantages:

- less configuration between service and gui needed
- no data transfer needed
- no need to create separate access layer (that could be disadvantage maybe, but in what case?)
- no inconsistencies between gui/service model (for example because of different protocol versions)
- easier to test and deploy
- no code duplication (normally we need to duplicate big part of the model)

That said, here is the diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after few more hours of thinking about this, I think I found solution which will satisfy my needs. The goals which I want to be fulfilled are:

1. Web GUI cannot make direct calls to the database; it need to use proper model which will in turn use some objects repository
2. It must be possible to test and deploy whole thing as one packet with minimum configuration (at least for development phase, and then it should be possible to easy switch to more flexible solution)
3. There should be no code duplication (i.e. the same code in the service and web gui model)
4. If one approach will appear to be wrong I need to be able to switch to other one

What I forget to say before is that my service will have some embedded cache used to aggregate and process the data, and then make commits to database with bigger chunks of them. It's also present on the diagram.

My class structure will look like this:

```
| 
|- models
    |- IElementsRepository.scala
    |- ElementsRepositoryJSON.scala
    |- ElementsRepositoryDB.scala
    |- Element.scala
    |- Service
         |- Element.scala
    |- Web
         |- Element.scala
|- controlers
    |- Element.scala
|- views
    |- Element
         |- index.scala.html
```

So it's like normal MVC web app except the fact that there are separate model classes for service and web gui inheriting from main one.
 
In the Element.scala I will have IElementsRepository object injected using DI (probably using Guice).
IElementsRepository have two concrete implementations:

1. ElementsRepositoryJSON allows to retrieve data from service through JSON
2. ElementsRepositoryDB allows to retrieve data from local cache and DB.

This means that depending on active DI configuration both service and web gui can get the data from other service or local/external storage.
So for early development I can keep everything in one Play! instance and use direct cache and DB access (through ElementsRepositoryDB) and later reconfigure web gui to use JSON (through ElementsRepositoryJSON). This also allows me to run gui and service as separated instances if I want. I can even configure service to use other services as data providers (however for now I don't have such a needs).

More or less it will look like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the RESTful service to connect to the database? Most Play! applications access the database directly from the controllers.  The [Play! philosophy](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/model) considers accessing your models through a service layer to be an anti-pattern.  The service layer could be handy if you intend to share that data with other (non-Play!) applications or external systems outside your control, but otherwise it's better to keep things simple.  But you could also simply expose the RESTful interface from the Play! application itself for the other systems.

Play! is about keeping things simple and avoiding the over-engineered nonsense that has plagued Java development in the past.

Comment: I will need this RESTful service to handle huge amount of statistical  data coming from various clients. Web gui will be much less loaded and used only to view and analyze this data. Hypothetically I can have situation where I'll need few/many RESTful service servers for gathering and processing the data and one gui server to display all the data. That's why I cannot just simply keep everything inside one Play! instance...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there's no objectively right or wrong answer here, but I'll offer my opinion: I think the diagram you've provided is exactly right.  Your RESTful service is the single point of access for all clients including your web front-end, and I'd say that's the way it should be.

Without saying anything about Play!, Spray or any other web frameworks (or, for that matter, any database servers, HTML templating libraries, JSON parsers or whatever), the obvious rule of thumb is to maintain a strict separation of concerns by keeping implementation details from leaking into your interfaces.  Now, you raised two concerns:

- **Performance:** The process of marshalling and unmarshalling objects into JSON representations and serving them over HTTP is plenty fast (compared to JAXB, for example) and well supported by Scala libraries and web frameworks.  When you inevitably find performance bottlenecks in a particular component, you can deal with those bottlenecks in isolation.
- **Testing and Deployment:** The fact that the Play! framework shuns servlets does complicate things a bit.  Normally I'd suggest for testing/staging, that you just take both the WAR for your front-end stuff and the WAR for your web service, and put them side-by-side in the same servlet container.  I've done this in the past using the [Maven Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin), for example.  This isn't so straightforward with Play!, but one module I found (and have never used) is the [play-cargo](https://github.com/dgouyette/play-cargo) module...  Point being, do whatever you need to do to keep the layers decoupled and then glue the bits together for testing however you want.

Hope this is useful...

Comment: That was exactly my idea when I was drawing this diagram few days ago. But now when I'm thinking about this, isn't this very close to anemic domain model anti-pattern? If I would use the same model for both RESTful service and web gui, then: (a) I'll avoid duplication and/or adm (b) I'll be able to directly access model without additional transfer of data. If I'll decouple service form the gui, then basically I need to transfer whole model through the web and then recreate it. What clear advantages this approach have?

Comment: Well, like I said: no objective right or wrong answer.  I happen to disagree with Fowler on his whole "anemic domain model" idea, and for that matter I don't really like heavyweight MVC web frameworks.  All I'm saying is, I think you should do whatever is needed to present a clean interface, and you should never circumvent the interface (for example, by accessing the database directly from the front-end).

Comment: Yea, I see your point. And even if I believe that there would be clear, consistent interface for both (the one provided by model itself) then still external clients have to use other one (RESTful). No matter how I look at this I see some bad smells with both approaches :(